# Trouble Running a Basic Report (Unit Activity) in Quickbooks Enterprise 14

Tags: report, quickbooks, enterprise

We are having trouble creating a simple report in Quickbook Enterprise 14 for Windows. We just switched from Sage 50.

We are used to running a report called a Unit Activity Report, It contains these headers:

Item #, Item Description, Last Cost, Units Sold, On Hand Qty, Qty on Po

We have all the headers setup except for "Units Sold". This report is crucial for our business. I have some experience with the ODBC Driver for Quickbooks Enterprise with Access so I could try and create the report there I just have no idea where to start.

Does anyone have any ideas or information for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in report that shows all of the columns that you would want. The closest one would be the "Inventory Stock Status by Item" under the Inventory report category. This report will not show the total units sold, but will show the average per week based on the date range you choose.

One solution that might be viable is to run the "Inventory Stock Status by Item" report, and then also run the "Sales by Item Summary" report (located under the Sales report category). The second report will show the total quantity sold. You could export these to Excel and combine them into one report (cut and paste).

If you were to go with the ODBC driver you'll end up needing to query the Item List for Item #, Description, and Cost, all sales transactions (Invoices, Sales Receipts, and Credit Memos) to get sales information, Open Purchase Orders. If you want On Hand as of the selected date and not just On Hand as of now, you'd also need to backout sales, credits, receiving, and item adjustments. It could end up being a bit complex. I'd probably use the two report method first until you get a bit more familiar with QuickBooks and the ODBC tables in QuickBooks.